# C3015: initialization in OpenMP 'for' statement has improper form

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-c++, openmp

I have Parallel Scan Algorithm: Hillis & Steele (1986) and I want to execute inner for loop parallel.

```
Error   C3015   initialization in OpenMP 'for' statement has improper form  OpenMP  c:\users\matja\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\psseminar\openmp\main.c
```

I never experienced this error before, I have googled around but found nothing useful.

Includes:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <windows.h>
```

Chunk of code:

```
// ...
for (long long m = 0; m < M; m++)
{
    long long offset = (long long)pow(2, m);

    #pragma omp parallel for firstprivate(N, m, offset)
    for (long long n = offset; n < N; n++)
    {
        long long ai = n - offset;
        long long bi = n;
        // ...
    }
}
// ...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to MSDN, the error that OP posted is raised when the OpenMP for is not fully explicited. This may happen because the compiler does not fully understand the C99 language used by the statement

```
for (long long n = offset; n < N; n++)
```

Despite I don't have a Visual C++ compiler, I see that gcc 4.8.5 and icc 16.0.3 fail to compile it requiring the code to be compiled with the appropriate C99 language variant (i.e. `-std=c99`). After googling a bit I have not found the proper flag for MSVC (in fact, wikipedia claims that support ins MSVC 2013 was limited (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99)). So one alternative you could try is to convert that code into

```
long long m;

for (m = 0; m < M; m++)
{
    long long offset = (long long)pow(2, m);
    long long n;

    #pragma omp parallel for firstprivate(N, m, offset)
    for (n = offset; n < N; n++)
    {
        long long ai = n - offset;
        long long bi = n;
        // ...
    }
}
```

Additionally, note that you probably can get rid off the `firstprivate` clause for `N`, `m` and `offset` and change them into `shared` if you dont modify within the parallel loop.

BTW, I disagree with tahini's answer where they claim that `#pragma omp parallel for` is restricted to `int` or `unsigned int` because the following code works flawslessly in either gcc 4.8.5 and icc 16.0.3.

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void main (void)
{
    long long m;

    #pragma omp parallel for schedule
    for (m = 0; m < 16; m++)
    {
            printf ("thread = %d, m = %d\n", omp_get_thread_num(), m);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The iteration variable in an **omp parallel for** is restricted to be an int or an unsigned int. The long long is not a valid iterator type.

See

https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/#ParallelRegion

Comment: I would expect int64_t to work on a suitable platform, but I suppose that's not a portable expectation.  Even if it works, it's probably slow on a platform without hardware support for it.

Comment: You may want to compare whether the inner or the outer loop being parallel is faster. Some people also use SIMD, and it is common to test multiple approaches.

Comment: This answer is not true. Simply check example number 29 from [OpenMP 4.0 examples](http://openmp.org/mp-documents/OpenMP4.0.0.Examples.pdf).

Comment: MSVC doesn't support OpenMP beyond 2.0, and it makes this distinction between C (restricted here to C89) and C++.  In VS2017 there seems to be more C89 support, but this painful issue remains.

Comment: VS2019 has the same issue. Must use C89 variable declaration, even for an int.