# OMP doesn't compile after enabling visual studio flag

Tags: c, openmp

My project is in c and visual studio 2022. This for loop compiles fine with "Open MP Support" set to "No" in the C/C++ language properties.

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int i=0; i < 10; i++)
{
    printf("numThreads = %d\n", omp_get_num_threads());
}
```

The problem was that it'd never use more than one thread even though omp_get_max_threads() told me there were 24 available.

So i went and enabled Open MP Support, and now the same for loop gives me the following error when i build: "initialization in OpenMP 'for' statement has improper form"

But my loop is very basic and seems to follow the guidelines. I would appreciate help understanding what's causing this.

Also, when i changed the code to:

```
#pragma omp parallel
for (int i=0; i < 10; i++)
{
    printf("numThreads = %d\n", omp_get_num_threads());
}
```

it compiled, but did not work as I expected, and according to another stack overflow post:

> #pragma omp parallel for instructs the comiler to parallelize the next for block. With #pragma omp parallel alone, you have many threads who
> run the same code. I.e. each thread runs the whole for cycle. The slow
> down comes from race conditions when several/all threads try to access
> the same memory. This is rookie mistake number one in using OpenMP.

so I'm definitely trying to use  #pragma omp parallel for.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/q/1448318/1216776

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38941157/c3015-initialization-in-openmp-for-statement-has-improper-form

Comment: Your links aren't helpful i'm using an int not a long long...?

Comment: Try declaring `i` before the loop (it should work also the way you have written it, but...)

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work :(

Comment: Is it possible that you have a compilation option that silentely promote all `int` to `long long`? Is `sizeof(int)` equal to `4`?

Comment: sorry you were correct, declaring i before fixed the issue. I think i mustn't have saved the first time. Thank you!

Comment: Looks like a compiler bug, though

Comment: apparently msvc is super outdated and requires c89 for loops for omp.